# How to compact variable in laravel without knowing if they are defined

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I have problem. I defined bunch of unique variables and I have no idea which of them are defined. How can i compact variables if I don`t know  if are they defined?

Comment: So you have dynamic/variable variables?

Comment: Yes I have dynamic variable(s)

Comment: Hello, do you have any update?

Comment: Save it to array is working. Only problem is when the variable is not defined at all. And I don't know which names the variable have and how to display them in blade.php if I don't know names and which of them are defined.

Comment: Actually you never said you wished to use it in a blade file in your question, but never mind, you can use the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend store all the variables values in array.
For example lets say you have a `$title`, `$content` and `$author` you have to pass from the controller to the view, you can do something like

```
$data = [
'title' => 'Some title',
'content' => 'Hello blah blah...',
'author' => 'Someone'
];
```

And then in the view file, you can output using `data_get('title',$data)`. `data_get()` is a laravel helper function that you can retrieve data from array and if the key doesn't exist, you will get `null` instead of throwing `undefined index` error message.